# Is there any way to set the delay of the focus?

Tags: unity, gnome, mouse, focus

I have used the Unity Tweak Tool to set focus behavior to "follow mouse" using the "sloppy" option.
This way when I mouse over a window it takes focus.

Is there any way to set the delay of the focus? 
In the Unity Tweak Tool it is possible to specify the delay for auto raise but not the delay for mouse focus.

This is particularly annoying when trying to move the mouse from a window to the menu in the top of the screen. On the way the desktop takes focus because of low delay in mouse focus and the menu is no longer available. I have disabled global application menu, but that is hardly the intended way to use mouse focus.

Best regards,
-thomas